# Count the number of times a value in a column is "X" and put it in a $variable

Tags: php, sql, count

I have an SQL DB table (AGENDA) with the following data:

```
DATE    TITTLE      CONTENT      STATUS
---------- -------- ---- ------------------ 
xx/xx/xx     title1      stuff        COMPLETE    
xx/xx/xx     tittle2     stuff        INCOMPLETE    
xx/xx/xx     tittle3     stuff        INCOMPLETE
```

I need a way to count the times that table (AGENDA) column (STATUS) is "INCOMPLETE", and have it placed in a variable $agendaInc then place it where the code below mentions "3".

```
<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
    <li class='dropdown'>
        <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button' aria-haspopup='true'
           aria-expanded='false'>AGENDA 
            <span class='caret'></span>
            &nbsp;<span class='badge'>3</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there anything else we can write for you as well as you appear to be too busy to do this yourself

Comment: Do you have any code to access the database? What are you using to access the database?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service
___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Comment: Jerodev - I'm trying to advance on my own on a website I'm being taught to bild, in other pages we are accessing the DB with $db->get_results(SELECT from AGENDA..... I'm just dont know how to count the number of times a value is repeated and put it on a variable.  I'm really a noob at this.. sorry

Comment: RiggsFolly - honestly if I knew how to do it myself I would be doing it, most likelly it takes just as much time to do it as it does to ask it here, probably less.. but I really dont know how. not even sure I'm asking the question the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow,

`$variable = db->get_results("select count(STATUS) FORM AGENDA WHERE STATUS = 'INCOMPLETE'")`

I don't know if you're using PDO or what other PHP driver for your database so I can't help you with that.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `select count(STATUS) FORM Agenda WHERE STATUS = 'INCOMPLETE'` be a whole lot simpler

Comment: thank you Arnold & RiggsFolly.. so to have it in a Variable I should go like: $variable=(SELECT count(STATUS) WHERE STATUS ="INCOMPLETE") ??

Comment: Yup... I was overthinking this haha. _edits answer_ @RiggsFolly

Comment: No @RuiNeves , Are you using PDO? Did you make a connection with your database yet?

Comment: @RuiNeves  You can easily google that. I don't think you want to learn how to program. [link](http://www.phptuts.nl/view/41/4/) tutorial for you. You have to connect to your mysql server via PHP. (Using the PDO driver)

Comment: @RuiNeves  Really how are we supposed to know how to help you if you have given us no information at all?! I could make an example for you how to do this with the Laravel Eloquent model using MongoDB and it would answer your question... Either give more information or you wont get any help. Or contact me and I'll do it for $50.

Comment: Judging from a previous comment he is using a library/framework of some kind..... `$db->get_results(SELECT from AGENDA.....` Which I agree is not helping you or any of us much

Comment: does MYSQL resembles anything?   Again.. sorry, but I really am new to this.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Maybe he's using Wordpress! That would explain everything.